# Run different function for the last item of the list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to do different task for my last item of the list. But I do task for all items, include the last, and then other task for the last again. For example, I have a list like text and choose button. Then in the end I need text, choose button and back button. Here's my code:

```
array = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"]

for item in array:
    theTask()
    if array.index(item) == len(array) - 1:
        theOtherTask()
```

I know my mistake, but that is the best result which I got. How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do, but probably something like

```
for item in array[:-1]:
    theTask()

item = array[-1]
theOtherTask()
```

Or

```
for index, item in enumerate(array):
    if index < len(array) - 1:
       theTask()
    else:
       theOtherTask()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to process for the last item both the_task and the_other_task and further using arguments to indicate what to work on and (which worker):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


def the_task(task):
    print('Working on', task)


def the_other_task(task):
    print('Working again on', task)


tasks = ("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5")

for task in tasks:
    the_task(task)
the_other_task(tasks[-1])
```

Note, I replaced the list with a tuple, as the use case did not require mutability, and also changed the names of the workers and provided some dummy print implementation.

On my machine the output is:

```
Working on string1
Working on string2
Working on string3
Working on string4
Working on string5
Working again on string5
```

So close to the answer provided by blue_note but including more pep8 changes as suggestions and also providing the added processing for the last item (instead of only the_other_task working on it).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are looking for but here is an improvement in your code.

```
array = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"]

for item in array:
    theTask()
    if item is array[len(array) - 1]:
        theOtherTask()
```

This will work even if you have duplicate items in your list.